# What happens if I put two NMVe drives, both of which have GRUB on them, in the same computer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, disk

I created a dual boot (Windows/Ubuntu) setup on an NMVe drive.  Both the Windows and Ubuntu partitions ended up with problems. So I took out the old NMVe, reinstalled Windows and Ubuntu on a new NMVe, and I now need to get the data off the old NMVe. If I put the old NMVe into the computer along with the new one, two SSDs will each have a GRUB installation on them.

What happens if I put both of these in the computer (a Dell T7910, using a Dell Ultraspeed Quad adapter) at once?

I suspect that what I need to do is to take the new NMVe out, put the old NMVe in, boot to a partition not on the NMVe, and delete the GRUB partition. Then I can put the new NMVe in with the old one, and clone the old Windows and Ubuntu partitions to the new partition.

If this won't work, or if there is a better way, I'd appreciate knowing about it.  Thanks!

Both NMVes are UEFI/GPT if that matters.

Comment: Your machine firmware decides which drive/device is important, ie. which one will be used.

Comment: Nothing happens. Either it will boot (or try to boot) from the old SSD or it will boot from the new one. You can change what you want to happen, (the boot order) in the UEFI settings.

Comment: ok, so if both nvme are on the same quad pcie card, then one will boot, or the other?

Comment: UEFI uses the GUID/partuuid to know which ESP - efi system partition to boot from. You can see that with `sudo efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` Most UEFI also now has fallback entry using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, for internal drives just like it uses for your USB/flash drives. If a drive is unplugged it may lose a specific entry like /EFI/ubuntu but many find the Windows /EFI/Microsoft and fallback entries automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever drive your computer tries to boot from first is determined by the boot sequence in the *Boot* tab of your computer's UEFI setup utility. In the boot sequence you can change the order in which the computer examines the storage devices when searching for a bootloader or you can disable a device in the boot sequence, so that the computer will not search for a bootloader on that storage device.